# Using Bootstrap 4, how to keep a text fixed over an image?

Tags: css, html

I have a background with a text appearing over it (when hovering the text). When I resize the window my background image shrink while the text doesn't. I want the text to stay at the same position over the picture. How would it be possible to have the text shrinking and staying at the same place when the image is reduce (because of a windows resize)?

Before resize :

[image: the image and description text before resize]

After resize :

[image: the image and description text after resize]

```
<div class="row two">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/portfolio.html">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/lyoon/image/upload/c_scale,h_350,w_500/v1510612416/windows-10-1995434_1280_xtmlea.png" class="img-fluid shadow" alt="My apps/games made" />
      <p class="img_description">Colt Steele Udemy Projects <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px grey;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px grey;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px grey;
}

.img_description {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding-top: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color:
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.img_description:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(139, 146, 152, 0.65);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some screenshots, I'm not sure I understand your problem?

Comment: I want my hover to stay inside like this http://res.cloudinary.com/lyoon/image/upload/v1510619795/Screen_Shot_2017-11-13_at_4.35.47_PM_xuhmf8.png

Comment: But when I resize to mobile size, the hover goes out of the box like this http://res.cloudinary.com/lyoon/image/upload/v1510619844/Screen_Shot_2017-11-13_at_4.35.06_PM_bmm4yl.png

Comment: Does anyone know? Or is my phrasing off? Someone help please

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into Media Queries.

You can set a threshold that will trigger separate styles under those conditions. It can be very useful when you want your UI to do something different at different sizes.

```
@media only screen 
and (*Your threshold criteria goes here* EXAMPLE:  max-width : 1000px) {   
  //css goes here with whatever css you want to fire at this threshold
}
```

I would just target your text class and set up a media query or two to make it behave. Let me know if you need further assistance.